# Excel filtering - remove rows with no value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have reached the limit of my excel skills on this problem... I am compiling a birdlist on Excel, but instead of having each bird on the list, I only want to display the ones that have been seen - in other words remove the birds (rows) from the list if not seen.

The list of seen birds for this example is in the "lifelist" column (column G), marked with 1 and hi-lighted green. Part of the problem is, I also want to include the family (black row) and order (grey row) headers if a species (white rows) has been seen in that order or family. The taxonomic order is ORDER -> FAMILY -> SPECIES.
In the provided example image, rows 201, 203-206, 210-211, 213, and 215 should be deleted or filtered out. and if, for instance, it was only the Greater Flamingo marked 1 in G200, rows 201-222 should be deleted or filtered out.

[image: birdlist exampla]

I started by assigning a value of 1 to column B if the row is a FAMILY heading, and a value of 1 in column A if the row is an ORDER heading. I then tried to automate formulas to count the number of species per FAMILY - but couldn't get that right as the number of species per FAMILY varies and there are ORDER rows in between. My thoughts were that if I have the number of Species per FAMILY, I could then determine the number of marked species in column G, subtract that from the FAMILY total, and if there is a difference between the FAMILY total and that worked out total, the FAMILY heading should be included. The plan was to apply the same principles for the ORDER headings, by determining the number of FAMILIES per ORDER, but I got stuck on the first part...

Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could create a VBA AutoFilter sub, this one filters for 'Not blank Cells' in Column 3 (Cell Range C1- C108):

```
Sub AutoFilter_Demo()

 Range("C1:C108").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlOr

End Sub
```

Comment: The species are all gone with this..

Comment: @Notus_Panda do you have the original dataset?

Comment: You can see from the picture that the C-column only has something there for the Order/Family

Comment: @Notus_Panda apologies, my demo wasn't meant to reference the species column it was just a basic demo, I don't know have enough information to write an exact sub

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have Office 365. This solution works there:

```
=LET(range,A198:K222,
     REDUCE({"Order","Family","Type","Specimen"}, FILTER(ROW(range)-MIN(ROW(range)-1),INDEX(range,,7)),
     LAMBDA(x,y,
            VSTACK(x,
LET(lkp,LAMBDA(searchtype,XLOOKUP(IF(searchtype="Type","Family",searchtype),INDEX(range,SEQUENCE(y),3),INDEX(range,SEQUENCE(y),4+6*(searchtype="Type")),,,-1)),
                   HSTACK(lkp("Order"),
                          lkp("Family"),
                          lkp("Type"),
                          INDEX(range,y,10)))))))
```

We start off by declaring the range of column `A:J` where your data is stored. we name it `range`.

Then I'm using lambda helper `REDUCE` with start value an array of the header values.
For the iteration I used a filter of the row numbers of `range` where column `G` holds a numerical value. Since we start the range at row 198 I want to subtract 197 from it, so I can use it inside INDEX. The iteration is named `y`, which will - in this example - start with `3` (3rd row of indexed range), next 11, 12, 17.

I then use another LAMBDA which I call `lkp` and is used as a function we can call within the function itself;
the function uses XLOOKUP and only needs an lookup string/value to be able to function. It will lookup the string in the 3rd column and return the value in the row number of the found value in the 4th column and will lookup from bottom to top. The size of the lookup/return range is equal to the sequence of `y`, so for each iteration it'll search for a different range sizes and since we use from last to first search mode, it'll return the last found value (or first found from the last technically).
Since the `Type` is to be found in another column, I added an if in the LAMBDA, so in that case only it returns the value from a different column (4th column +6 = column J).

Now if I call off this function with `lkp("Order")`, it'll lookup for "Order" in column 3 from range row 1-3 column 3 and return the same range, but column 4 (search mode last to first).
Same for `'lkp("Family"), but it'll lookup "Family" which will return a different row and same for Type, however this will return the value of column 10.

And I needed to HSTACK these values along with the indexed range with row `y` column 10 to return the actual specimen of the bird (not sure if specimen is the correct term).

Next iteration it'll repeat these steps, but with the different range size (up to row 11, next 12, next 17).

These iterations are VSTACKED starting off with the headers (REDUCE start value) next the HSTACKED results per iteration.

[image]

I'm not sure this was the intended output of what you had in mind, but I liked the challenge anyway. Thanks.

An alternative solution using MAP/TEXTSPLIT:

`=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(", "&MAP(FILTER(ROW(J198:J222),G198:G222),LAMBDA(x,ARRAYTOTEXT(HSTACK(XLOOKUP({"Order","Family"},C198:INDEX(C:C,x),D198:INDEX(D:D,x),,,-1),XLOOKUP("Family",C198:INDEX(C:C,x),J198:INDEX(J:J,x),,,-1),INDEX(J:J,x))))),", ",{1,2,3,4}),", ")`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite get my logic through to Excel so I went to VBA. (yes, I was a bit lazy with the amount I typed over but it gets the job done)

```
Sub keepCorrectRows()
    Dim lRow As Long, dictKeep As Object
    Dim rng As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("S-AfricanList") 'adjust sheet as needed
    With ws
        lRow = .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("A2:J" & lRow) 'adjust starting row 
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    rng.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    
    Dim curOrder As String, curFamily As String
    Dim arr, i As Long
    
    arr = rng.Value
    Set dictKeep = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(i, 1) = 1 Then curOrder = arr(i, 4) 'Current order
        If arr(i, 2) = 1 Then curFamily = arr(i, 4) 'Current Family
        If arr(i, 7) = 1 Then 'Lifelist has a 1 -> save all needed names to dictionary
            If Not dictKeep.exists(curOrder) Then dictKeep.Add curOrder, ""
            If Not dictKeep.exists(curFamily) Then dictKeep.Add curFamily, ""
            dictKeep.Add arr(i, 10), ""
        End If
    Next i
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If Not dictKeep.exists(arr(i, 4)) And Not dictKeep.exists(arr(i, 10)) Then
            Range("A" & i + 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True 'hide unneeded rows
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub

Sub testShowAll()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("S-AfricanList").UsedRange.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    'Don't forget to adjust this Sheet-name
End Sub
```

This code goes into a module and the following in the Sheet-code:

```
Private Sub btnAll_Click()
    testShowAll
End Sub

Private Sub btnFilter_Click()
    keepCorrectRows
End Sub
```

Or have the respective codes into the corresponding btn subs.

Also could have worked with Union to hide them all at once but I'm not sure how big your list is and therefor if there's a need for it.

[image]

[image]

If there's anything unclear, let me know.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are trying to create a dynamic filter in Excel based on the values in the "lifelist" column (column G) and the taxonomy headers (ORDER and FAMILY).

One way to approach this problem is to use Excel's advanced filter feature with a custom formula. Here's a general outline of the steps you can take:

1. Use the COUNTIFS function to count the number of seen species within each family and order. For example, in a new column next to the family heading, you can use a formula like `=COUNTIFS($G:$G, 1, $E:$E, "Family Name")` to count the number of seen species within that family.
2. Use a similar approach to count the number of seen families within each order.
3. Use these counts to create a custom filter formula. For example, you can use a formula like `=OR($G2=1, AND($A2=1, $H2>0), AND($B2=1, $I2>0))` to filter rows where the species is seen, or the family has seen species, or the order has seen families.
4. Apply the advanced filter with this custom formula to display only the relevant rows.

Please note that this is a simplified approach, and you may need to adapt it to your specific data structure and requirements. It's also possible that a more complex solution using VBA or Power Query may be necessary for a more dynamic and automated solution.